# py-bcrypt installing on win 7 64bit python

Tags: python, c, gcc, compiler-construction, module

Trying to install py-bcrypt on win7. Python is 64bit. First error unable to find vcvarsall.bat. Googled a bit learned that i needed to install mingw. installed it now this

```
C:\tools\python_modules\py-bcrypt-0.2>python setup.py build -c mingw32
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'bcrypt._bcrypt' extension
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall -Ic:\Python27\include -Ic:\Python27\PC -c bcrypt/bcrypt_python.c -o b
d\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\bcrypt\bcrypt_python.o
bcrypt/bcrypt_python.c:29:26: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'u_int8_t'
bcrypt/bcrypt_python.c:29:38: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'u_int16_t'
bcrypt/bcrypt_python.c:29:49: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'u_int8_t'
bcrypt/bcrypt_python.c: In function 'bcrypt_encode_salt':
bcrypt/bcrypt_python.c:56:2: error: too many arguments to function 'encode_salt'
bcrypt/bcrypt_python.c:29:6: note: declared here
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

no idea what to do next. guess i'll just not use bcrypt and try something else. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and I fixed it by applying the patch found at this link:

http://code.google.com/p/py-bcrypt/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=1

py-bcrypt_11.patch

Had to apply it manually.

From that thread, the source of the problem is

> According to http://groups.google.com/group/mpir-devel/msg/2c2d4cc7ec12adbb (flags defined under the various windows OS'es ,cygwins,mingw's and other's) its better to use _WIN32 instead of _MSC_VER, Together with the change from bzero to memset this compiles both under MSVC and MingW32.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 7):

There is a compiled version of py-bcrypt for windows. You can visit https://bitbucket.org/alexandrul/py-bcrypt/downloads to download the .exe file and install.

Comment: Know if this will have 0.4 anytime soon?

Comment: @Joe I just added the 0.4 wheels.

Comment: Can't find .exes there?

Answer (score 3):

I've looked at the bcrypt source, and can't figure out why you're getting the error you are (don't have a Windows system at hand to test on right now). Though looking at the pybcrypt [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/py-bcrypt/issues/list) it looks like it has other Windows compilation problems, so it's probably not just you. At a guess though, adding "--std=C99" to the gcc arguments via extra_compile_args might fix at least some of the errors.

Aside from that, there are a couple of alternatives -

- [Bcryptor](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Bcryptor) is another C-extension bcrypt implementation which may compile for your system.
- [Passlib](http://packages.python.org/passlib) is a general password hashing library. While it relies on bcryptor/pybcrypt for bcrypt support, it has builtin support for a number of other password hashes that may work for you - such as [SHA512-Crypt](http://packages.python.org/passlib/lib/passlib.hash.sha512_crypt.html) or [PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA512](http://packages.python.org/passlib/lib/passlib.hash.pbkdf2_digest.html)
- [Cryptacular](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/cryptacular/) is another general password hashing library. On Windows, it provides both BCrypt and PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA512 password hashes. *(I'd link straight to those, but the documentation won't quite let me)*.

Comment: I guess windows was just not cut for this :) i may just stay with simple hashlib.sha512 and thats it . more errors from bcryptor. ill try cryptacular next and that's that.

Comment: ok cryptacular works. it's bcrypt works. question. am i not supposed to salt bcrypt? just asking.

Comment: If you're following the example at the top of the Cryptacular docs, `manager.encode(password)` takes care of salt generation... you can test this by running `manager.encode("test")` twice, and you'll see the hash is different - this shows it's taking care of generating a new salt. ([this page](http://packages.python.org/passlib/lib/passlib.hash.bcrypt.html#format-algorithm) gives a brief description of the bcrypt hash string format if you're curious).

Comment: Ok hold on. So i dont need to separately store the salt? the rounds and salt are stored inside the hash?

Comment: Yep... in fact all the password hashes in the libraries I linked to are completely self-contained, and the code handles salt generation automatically. Calling .encode() for Cryptacular / .encrypt() for Passlib does all of it for you... then just call .verify() to check the password. If you want a different number of rounds than the default, just pass that as rounds=value to when you call encode().

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled upon this rather old thread while trying to get py-bcrypt installed (via pip) on Windows 7 using VS2012. Apparently, this still doesn't work (I also get the "missing vcvars.bat" error).

There is a dedicated Windows fork for py-bcrypt called [py-bcrypt-w32](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py-bcrypt-w32), which I could install without any problems using

```
pip install py-bcrypt-w32
```

Comment: IMO this should be the accepted answer. Just use py-bcrypt-w32 vs py-bcrypt for dev on windows with two different requirements.txt files for each environment.

Answer (score 0):

supposing you are using mingw64, you should change _MSC_VER in _WIN32 on ifdefs into bcrypt.c, bcrypt_python.c and pybc_blf.h

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem with python 3.4.1, and none of the previous answers worked. I eventually got the Visual Studio 2010 64-bit compiler working, and hence both cryptacular and py-bcrypt installed with easy_install. See my detailed answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27033824/3800244

Answer (score 0):

It's 2016 and I have faced same issue. Download the wheel directly from https://bitbucket.org/alexandrul/py-bcrypt/downloads and then run following

```
pip install <whl-file>
```