# A multitude of problems trying to install Python bcrypt on Windows (x64)

Tags: python, windows, windows-7, windows64

This problem has been mentioned [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096990/py-bcrypt-installing-on-win-7-64bit-python), but it does not provide a working solution, so I would still like to keep a ticket open.

```
c:\Users\me\Desktop\temp\py-bcrypt-0.2>setup.py install build --compiler=min
gw32
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'bcrypt._bcrypt' extension
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC -c bcrypt/bcrypt_python.c -o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\bcrypt\bcrypt_python.o
bcrypt/bcrypt_python.c:29:26: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'u_int8_t'
bcrypt/bcrypt_python.c:29:38: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'u_int16_t'
bcrypt/bcrypt_python.c:29:49: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'u_int8_t'
bcrypt/bcrypt_python.c: In function 'bcrypt_encode_salt':
bcrypt/bcrypt_python.c:56:2: error: too many arguments to function 'encode_salt'

bcrypt/bcrypt_python.c:29:6: note: declared here
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

This is after getting rid of the initial **[“error: Setup script exited with error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat”](http://blog.eddsn.com/2010/05/unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat/)**, I am left with what seems like a Gordic knot. `pip` and `easy-install` do not work. I have also read a number of [other](https://github.com/brownan/Minecraft-Overviewer/wiki/Build-Instructions) articles.

I don’t need to implement bcrypt at the moment, so it is not an urgent matter, but obviously, implementing a secure password protection is vital.

Answer (score 0):

supposing you are using mingw64, you should change _MSC_VER in _WIN32 on ifdefs into bcrypt.c, bcrypt_python.c and pybc_blf.h

(I've also replied the other question)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I found was to download and install windows binaries, rather than trying to compile myself. [This guy has some on bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/alexandrul/py-bcrypt/downloads)