# How to logout from a simple web appl. in CherryPy, Python

Tags: python, authentication, logout, cherrypy

I am not familiar with CherryPy and Python, but I need to write a very simple web application that performs login ---> do some commands ---> logout. For login I am using the code in the following link:

http://tools.cherrypy.org/wiki/AuthenticationAndAccessRestrictions

the application is:

```
import cherrypy
import os.path
import struct
from auth import AuthController, require, member_of, name_is

class Server(object):
    led_power=0 
    led_switch=1 #Initial LED on

    _cp_config = {
        'tools.sessions.on': True,
        'tools.auth.on': True
    }   
    auth = AuthController()      
    @cherrypy.expose
    @require()
    def index(self,  switch='', power=''):
        if switch:
            self.led_switch = int(switch)
        if power:
            self.led_power = int(power)  

        html = open('led.html','r').read()

        if self.led_switch:
            print "ON"
        else:
            print "OFF"

        if self.led_power:
            print "Logout"
            cherrypy.session.clear()

        return html
    index.exposed = True


conf = {
    'global' : { 
        'server.socket_host': '0.0.0.0', #0.0.0.0 or specific IP
        'server.socket_port': 8080 #server port
    },

    '/images': { #images served as static files
        'tools.staticdir.on': True,
        'tools.staticdir.dir': os.path.abspath('images')
    },

    '/favicon.ico': {  #favorite icon
        'tools.staticfile.on': True,  
        'tools.staticfile.filename': os.path.abspath("images/bulb.ico")
    }
}
cherrypy.quickstart(Server(), config=conf)
```

and the html file is:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<br>
<a href="?switch=1"><img src="images/on.png"></a>
<a href="?switch=0"><img src="images/off.png"></a>
<p>
<a href="?power=1"><img src="images/Logout.png"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

with a folder contain three images.

When I run the application I can see the login page on the localhost with username and password fields, then I can reach to the web page which has three button "ON, OFF, Logout".

The problem is I must click the logout button twice to logout, and when I login again and click on any button even the ON or OFF buttons the page is logout and show me  the login page again.
I cannot logout in a right way, any help please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running this code.  It calls the AuthController().logout() function.

```
import cherrypy
import os.path
import struct
from auth import AuthController, require, member_of, name_is

class Server(object):
    led_power=0 
    led_switch=1 #Initial LED on

_cp_config = {
    'tools.sessions.on': True,
    'tools.auth.on': True
}   
auth = AuthController()      
@cherrypy.expose
@require()
def index(self,  switch='', power=''):
    if switch:
        self.led_switch = int(switch)
    if power:
        self.led_power = int(power)  

    html = open('led.html','r').read()

    if self.led_switch:
        print "ON"
    else:
        print "OFF"

    if self.led_power:
        print "Logout"
        AuthController().logout()

        return html
    index.exposed = True


conf = {
    'global' : { 
        'server.socket_host': '0.0.0.0', #0.0.0.0 or specific IP
        'server.socket_port': 8080 #server port
    },

    '/images': { #images served as static files
        'tools.staticdir.on': True,
        'tools.staticdir.dir': os.path.abspath('images')
    },

    '/favicon.ico': {  #favorite icon
        'tools.staticfile.on': True,  
        'tools.staticfile.filename': os.path.abspath("images/bulb.ico")
    }
}
cherrypy.quickstart(Server(), config=conf)
```

Hope this helps.

Andrew

Comment: Thanks Andrew for reply, but when I click on logout button I got the following:

Comment: Thanks Andrew, but when I click on Logout button I got the following:500 Internal Server Error

The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 606, in respond
    cherrypy.response.body = self.handler()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/cherrypy/_cpdispatch.py", line 25, in __call__
    return self.callable(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "run.py", line 33, in index
    auth.logout()
NameError: global name 'auth' is not defined

Comment: I've edited my response.  Try AuthController().logout().  Hope this helps.

Comment: I just tried with AuthController().logout(), It is logout now but I cannot login again, its always ask me to "Enter login information" even when I close that session and open a new one!!! Thanks

Comment: hmmmm, what url are you redirected to after you logout?  Perhaps you're continually going to /?power=1.  If that's the case try AuthController().logout('/?switch=1').  Let me know if you still have problems.

Comment: When click logot, the url is http://192.168.15.158:8080/auth/login?from_page=/    when I changed to AuthController().logout('/?switch=1'), I still have the same problem but the url after logout in this case is http://192.168.15.158:8080/auth/login?from_page=/%3Fswitch%3D1

Comment: Hi Andrew,I just tried with AuthController().logout('/?power=0') and now its work fine. Thank you so much for help. Andrew, is this the most secure authentication method in Cherrypy/Python? Thanks

Comment: Awesome - glad to hear!  If my solution helped you please accept it as your answer.  The AuthController is an extension of tools.sessions library built into CherryPy.  I have not heard of it having any insecurities.  However, be sure to salt and hash your passwords... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594125/salt-and-hash-a-password-in-python