# Hashing in python (encrypting)

Tags: python, encryption, hash, passwords

i am trying to implement a encryption into my login program, i've looked for help in many places but i can't seem to understand any of it.
Im fairly new to python and im warming up for a university course in it. 
im interested in if it is possible to implement it as a class in my already excisting program, any tips or explanations would be greatly appreciated

So basicly what im asking is, how would it look if i wanted the program to encrypt the passwords between runs and the decrypt them again so that the program can use them when it runs.

Program:

```
import json 

with open("login_data.txt", "r") as login_file:
    try:
        users = json.load(login_file)
    except:
        users = {}

status = ""

def Display_Menu():

    status = input("Are you a registered user? (y/n)? Press q to quit: ")
    if status == "y":
        Old_User()
    elif status == "n":
        New_User()
    elif status == "passwd":
        Change_Passwd()
    elif status == "q":
        skriva = open("login_data.txt", "w")
        json.dump(users, skriva)
    return status

def New_User():

    Create_Login =input("Create login name: ")
    if Create_Login in users:
        print ("Login name already exist!")
    else:
        Create_Password =input("Create password: ")
        users[Create_Login] = Create_Password
        print("New User created!")        
    current_user = None

def Old_User():
    global current_user  

    login =input("Enter login name: ")
    Password =input("Enter password: ")

    if login in users and users[login] == Password:

        print("Login successful!")  
        current_user = login
        status = input("Wanna quit, change pass, och logout?")       
        if status == "passwd":
            Change_Passwd()
        elif status == "logout":
            Display_Menu()
        elif status == "q":
            skriva = open("login_data.txt", "w")
            json.dump(users, skriva)
        return status

    else:
        print("User doesn't exist or wrong password!")

def Change_Passwd():    
    oldpass =input("Old password: ")

    if current_user in users and users[current_user] == oldpass:
        Create_Password = input("New password: ")
        users[current_user] = Create_Password

        if Create_Password == input("Confirm password: "):
            print("Password changed!")
        else:
            print("User authorization failure")
            users[current_user] = oldpass
    else:
        print ("No password match!")

while status != "q":            
    status = Display_Menu()
```

Comment: Not sure whether you are asking about password hashing, or specifically how to implement it in Python. For the former, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326699/difference-between-hashing-a-password-and-encrypting-it?rq=1 for the latter, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594125/salt-and-hash-a-password-in-python

Comment: More background on password hashing: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords

Answer (score 0):

MD5 is a really simple hashing algorithm, this is some sample usage:

```
>>> hashlib.md5("String you want to encrypt").hexdigest()
'096a773d70e934d03ae3dd8022deed5e'
```

MD5 is by no means secure, but it is sufficient to illustrate some points. You could for instance store usernames and hashed passwords in some format of your choosing, ie.:

```
username1, hash1
username2, hash2
```

This ([Difference between Hashing a Password and Encrypting it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326699/difference-between-hashing-a-password-and-encrypting-it?rq=1)) could be a relevant read.

Comment: all i want is a simple encrypt and decrypt function im trying to find a easy way to implement it.                                               
   **code
Def Old_User():
    global current_user  

    login =input("Enter login name: ")
    #print(users[login]) <- here is where i would like to decrypt it
    Password =input("Enter password: ")
  code**
And then encrypt it before the program saves the password to the file

file looks like name = login_data  and typed in it "{"halo": "molly"}"

@Padraic Cunningham

Comment: Also, why don't **code password = input("Password: ")
encrypt = hashlib.md5(password).hexdigest()
code**
Get the error "Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing"

Comment: It's possible you have to use password.encode("utf-8") before hashing.

Answer (score 0):

[bcrypt](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bcrypt/1.0.1) is a library you should have a look at.

```
import bcrypt
password = b"super secret password"
# Hash a password for the first time, with a randomly-generated salt
hashed = bcrypt.hashpw(password, bcrypt.gensalt())
# Check that a unhashed password matches one that has previously been
#   hashed
if bcrypt.hashpw(password, hashed) == hashed:
    print("It Matches!")
else:
    print("It Does not Match :(")
```