# python 3.5 : "TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'"

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I am using python `3.5.2` and scrapy `1.1.1`.

There is an error when running the code below:

```
#-*- coding:utf-8-*-

import random
import base64


class ProxyMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        proxy = random.choice(PROXIES)
        if proxy['user_pass'] is not None:
            request.meta['proxy'] = "http://%s" % proxy['ip_port']
            encoded_user_pass = base64.encodebytes(proxy['user_pass'])
            request.headers['Proxy-Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + encoded_user_pass
            print("ok!" + proxy['ip_port'])
        else:
            print("fail!" + proxy['ip_port'])
            request.meta['proxy'] = "http://%s" % proxy['ip_port']
```

error:

```
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\base64.py", line 518, in _input_type_check
    m = memoryview(s)
    TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I think the error is related to  this sentence:

```
encoded_user_pass = base64.encodebytes(proxy['user_pass'])
```

But I don't know how to solve it.
Some help please,
thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

```
encoded_user_pass = base64.encodebytes(proxy['user_pass'])
```

was changed to

```
encoded_user_pass = base64.encodebytes(proxy['user_pass'].encode())
```

there is another error:

```
    request.headers['Proxy-Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + encoded_user_pass
TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly
```

what should I do?

Comment: Just FYI base64 encoding the password is insecure and pretty much does nothing in terms of security. You should look into salt hashing for a more secure way of doing it; check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594125/salt-and-hash-a-password-in-python

Comment: @Granitosaurus thanks,I will try it later.now there is another error,see my edit ,thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Function `base64.encodebytes()` is expecting bytes value and it seems like you are providing it a string.

To fix that you can simply encode your string value (encode() function turns your string object into bytes object):

```
base64.encodebytes('foo'.encode())
```

or in your case:

```
encoded_user_pass = base64.encodebytes(proxy['user_pass'].encode())
```

Comment: Regarding your edit: Your error here means that one value is `string` the other one is `bytes` and when you try to add them python gets a bit confused. You should either convert both to bytes with `str.encode()` or convert both to string with `bytes.decode()`. You can just fix it with `b'Basic' + encoded_user_pass` in this specific case.

Answer (score 2):

As the name suggests, [`base64.encodebytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.encodebytes) encodes *bytes*, not strings. As outlined in the documentation, it requires a [bytes-like object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-bytes-like-object) (just like the error message also tells you).

Your `proxy['user_pass']` value is a string however. In order to convert that into bytes, call [`str.encode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode):

```
encoded_user_pass = base64.encodebytes(proxy['user_pass'].encode())
```