# Securely hashing an SSN to fit in a BIT column or extending a BIT column to fit a secure hash?

Tags: mysql, sql, security

This is an extension of my previous question - [How to securely and efficiently store SSN in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41599285/how-to-securely-and-efficiently-store-ssn-in-a-database)

The idea is, I have social security numbers that I want to securely hash, and then insert into a column, and index that column. Then I can quickly find users who have multiple accounts with the same SSN.

I was on my way using PBKDF2 and SHA256, but I completely missed that MySql limits BIT columns to 64bits. I have 256bits. I'm not sure where to go. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Don't use a `BIT` column, use `CHAR`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use BINARY instead of BIT.

This solved my issue.