# Attribute error: Type object "Client " has no attribute "get

Tags: python, postgresql, pyramid

I am using pyramid framework with BD postgres, I am doing a login, but I have the following error "Attribute error: Type object" Client "has no attribute" get ""."

@view_config(route_name='login', renderer='templates/login.pt')

```
def login(request):
    a = request.params.get('login1')
    contrasenia = request.params.get('password1')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if a and Client.get(a) == contrasenia:
            headers = remember(request, a)
            return HTTPFound('/', headers=headers)
    return {}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error describes the issue. This line is the problem:

```
    if a and Client.get(a) == contrasenia:
```

The object `Client` does not have an attribute of `get`.  Sorry, I have no clue what that object could be based on the information provided.

I suggest working through the official Pyramid [SQLAlchemy + URL dispatch wiki tutorial](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/tutorials/wiki2/index.html). Although it uses SQLite for a database, the concepts apply to Postgres as well. The step on authentication has pertinent details for your specific issue, too.

Answer (score 0):

If im guessing right you are probably trying to authenticate user.

First name your variables appropriately:

```
email = request.params.get('email')
password = request.params.get('password')
```

Then query the Client by email (im guessing you are using SQLAlchemy):

```
client = Session.query(Client).filter(Client.email == email).first()
```

If client exists for given email then check password hashes(search the web about password security, example solutions: [Salt and hash a password in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594125/salt-and-hash-a-password-in-python))

```
if client.password_hash == hashing_func(password):
    return HTTPFound('/', headers=remeber(request, client.id))
```