# How can I check if a user and password is already in the MySQL database using Python?

Tags: python, mysql, scripting, pymysql

I have a html login form.which collects a  users username and password . I also have a script which collects them and stores it . I was wondering if it was possible to check if the username and password already exists in the MySQL database before storing in the database.

Html form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="login.py" method="GET">
        First name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="user_name"><br>
        Last name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="password"><br>
    </form>
</body>
</html>



Login script





import cgitb
   cgitb.enable()

   import cgi
   form = cgi.FieldStorage()
   user_name = form["user_name"].value
   password = form["password"].value

   import pymysql
   conn = pymysql.connect(db='userdb', 
   user='root', passwd='12346', 
   host='localhost')
   cursor = conn.cursor()

   query= "INSERT INTO users VALUES 
   ('{user_name}',{password})"   
 cursor.execute(query.format(user_name=user- 
    name, password=password))
    conn.commit()
```

Is it possible to check if the username and password from the html form  has a match in the database?

Comment: Avoid SQL inection by using [cursor.execute](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) correctly (aka don't use `query.format`).

Comment: And don't store user passwords in clear text. Use a [salted hash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23768422/3929826)!

Answer (score 0):

Make unique or primary key on `user_name` and if a duplicate occurs and exception will be thrown.

If you're storing passwords in an unhashed format, shame on you, er [fix it](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet#Use_a_cryptographically_strong_credential-specific_salt),

If you have passwords as hashes you can't tell if they are duplicates (which isn't a bad thing).