# Check if username exist or not in python when registering

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to check if the username exist in the table or not.The code is working when i select everything from the table but i get a error when i only try username.The error i get is

File "\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1705, in **call**
    return self.func(*args)

File /Calculator_calorie/login_register.py", line 89, in create

```
login_backend.insert(self.namere_text.get(),self.passwordr1e_text.get())
```

File \Calculator_calorie\login_backend.py", line 18, in insert

```
if cur.execute('SELECT name FROM user WHERE name = ?',(name)):
```

sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 4 supplied.

```
import sqlite3
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from user import user

def connect():
    conn=sqlite3.connect("login.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE if NOT exists user(name text,password text)")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()



def insert(name,password):
    conn=sqlite3.connect('login.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    if cur.execute('SELECT * FROM user WHERE name = ?', (name)):
        if cur.fetchone():
          messagebox.showinfo('Error', 'User already exist')
        else:
           cur.execute('INSERT INTO user VALUES(?,?)', (name, password))
           messagebox.showinfo('Register', 'Entry sucess')


    conn.commit()
    conn.close()




def create(self):
         if self.passwordr1e.get() != self.passwordr2e.get():
             messagebox.showinfo('error','Passwords do not match')
         elif len(self.namere.get()) == 0:
             messagebox.showinfo('error', 'Name field is empty')

         elif len(self.passwordr1e.get()) == 0:
               messagebox.showinfo('error', 'PASSWORD field is empty')

         else:
             login_backend.insert(self.namere_text.get(),self.passwordr1e_text.get())
```

Comment: To make a single element tuple, write "(name,)". Without comma it is same as "name" which is interpreted as sequence of characters here.

Comment: still gives me the same error

Comment: Please don't write passwords without hashing them into your database.

Comment: Is the shown code the one creating problems? If not, show that. Also show the full traceback of the error message.

Comment: Your database should do this for you. Make sure your username column is `unique` and handle the insert error when you have a duplicate. Querying first and then inserting is (a) unnecessary and (b) not reliable unless you also add the `unique` constraint due to race conditions.

Comment: My initial comment applies yet.

Answer (score 1):

[As Michael commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60178716/check-if-username-exist-or-not-in-python-when-registering#comment106440235_60178716), for Python to recognize a tuple with a single value it needs a comma at the end. `(name,)` not `(name)`. See [W3Schools Python Tuples](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_tuples.asp).

```
if cur.execute('SELECT name FROM user WHERE name = ?',(name,)):
```

Note that if you're just checking if a row exists, `select 1` to save a bit of time.

---

However, there's a safer and faster way to do this.

[As Chris commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60178716/check-if-username-exist-or-not-in-python-when-registering/60179092#comment106440493_60178716), checking for a user and inserting if they're not contains a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). If two processes try to create the same user at the same time they will both think it's not there and both insert resulting in a duplicate.

```
     Proc 1                                       Proc 2
t    SELECT * FROM user WHERE name = ?
i                                                 SELECT * FROM user WHERE name = ?
m    0 records found
e                                                 0 records found
|    INSERT INTO user VALUES(?,?)
v                                                 INSERT INTO user VALUES(?,?)
```

Instead, set up a [unique constraint](https://www.w3schools.com/sqL/sql_unique.asp), do the `insert`, and catch the unique error.

```
CREATE TABLE if NOT exists user(
  name text unique not null,
  password text not null
)

def insert(name,password):
    conn=sqlite3.connect('login.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()

    try:
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO user VALUES(?,?)', (name, password))
        messagebox.showinfo('Register', 'Entry sucess')
    except sqlite3.IntegrityError as e:
        if re.match(r'UNIQUE constraint failed', e.args[0]):
            messagebox.showinfo('Error', 'User already exist')
        else:
            raise e

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Doing the check for existence and insert in a single query is referred to as being "atomic" because the two parts cannot be separated.

---

## Notes

Writing SQL by hand is good for learning, but for production work use a framework such as [SQL Alchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/).

Storing passwords as plain text is insecure. [Use a password hashing library such as bcrypt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23768422/14660) and read up on [password hashing](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm).

Reconnecting to the database for every query is inefficient. Connect once and keep the connection open.