# login with comparison of hashed password

Tags: python, authentication, hash, passwords, sha256

I'm trying to do a simple login system with python that will check the hash (sha256) of a password a then let the user in, but is not working.  I've tried many different forms of doing so, but this is the best one I could come up.

```
import hashlib

username = input("Enter username: ")
password = input("Enter password: ")

#hashing password
password = hashlib.sha256(password.encode())
t_hash = password.hexdigest()
print(t_hash)
if username == "kent" and password == "a665a45920422f9d417e4867efdc4fb8a04a1f3fff1fa07e998e86f7f7a27ae3":
    print("Clark Kent logged!")
else:
    print("Wrong credentials")
```

As expected it is not working and I don't know what I'm missing. Can anybody help me?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

you should have match `t_hash` not `password` in `if` clause

```
if username == "kent" and t_hash == "a665a45920422f9d417e4867efdc4fb8a04a1f3fff1fa07e998e86f7f7a27ae3":
      print("Clark Kent logged!")
else:
      print("Wrong credentials")
```

Don't use `sha256` for hashing password use other better `PBKDF2`,`bcrypt` etc matching password with `==` not good idea.

https://qvault.io/cryptography/hashing-passwords-python-cryptography-examples/

[Salt and hash a password in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594125/salt-and-hash-a-password-in-python)