# MYSQL and Python: Add salt after the first two characters of the password

Tags: python, mysql, hash, passwords, salt

I am working in MYSQL and Python. I have a table that stores users login information and want to make this secure. How do I add the salt after the first two characters of the password? I am then going to hash it using sha256.

The table looks like this:

| username | password | salt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| test | testing123 | abc09 |

I made the table using like this, bit if there is something you can implement here I am happy to redo it.

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `salt` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL
);
```

Later I am going to use python to unhash and retrieve the password.

Comment: You do not "unhash" a password, you hash the login input and check it. if you use bcrypt like here, salt is part of the hash result: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594125/salt-and-hash-a-password-in-python

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it is easier to do this thru python. I hash the password and insert the salt using hashlib.